# Restore Eclipse Workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I zipped my whole workspace once in a while and want to reanimate it now. Some stupid sync crashed my current state. What I tried is to unzip it and then changed the workspace of eclipse to the newly generated folder.
The problem now, my Eclipse is blank containing now projects at all, the Package Explorer is empty, even after pressing F5? Any suggestions?
Do I have to use same Eclipse Version, which I used when producing the zips? Does a Computer change from 32 to 64 Bit  or visaversa make a difference.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange is that if I try to import one of the Project from existing source, Eclipse tells me that the Project allready exists and all of them are back. Still a strange behavoir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete your .metadata folder and re-import the projects manually.  The metadata will be automatically regenerated.

Comment: I don't like to do that, sience there are a lot of projects

Answer (score 1):

Did your zip file contain the hidden `.metadata` folder? (This is where Eclipse stores preferences and launch options.) If not, that may be reason why you don't see your projects as before.

You can try to import existing projects. Then you should at least see the projects again.